# What all does Blood Moon affect?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

1: If [Blood Moon](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Blood%20Moon) is on the battlefield, will [Back to Basics](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Back%20to%20Basics), [Burning Earth](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Burning%20Earth), etc. have any effect?
2: What about [Urborg, Tomb of Yawgmoth](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Urborg%2C%20Tomb%20of%20Yawgmoth)?
3: Will a nonbasic with [Wild Growth](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Wild%20Growth) get an extra green mana?
4: What about [Awaken the Ancient](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Awaken%20the%20Ancient) on a nonbasic mountain?
5: Can a nonbasic with [Abundant Growth](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Abundant%20Growth) still tap for any color?

Comment: Please stick to one question per post. We don't mind getting lots of questions, as long as each of them demonstrate research effort on the behalf of the author.

Comment: I asked all of these in one question because they all concern Blood Moon specifically

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Yes, the will work normally. Blood Moon only changes the subtype to mountain, it doesn't add the supertype "basic". "Mountain" as a card name and "mountain" as a subtype of land are different things.
2. Urbog will have no effect. Urbog will be turned into a mountain, so it will lose its ability to make other lands into swamps. Urbog's effect depends on Blood Moon effect because of rule 613.7a, so Blood Moon effect is always applied first, and Urbog's ability is lost.
3. Yes, that mana is added because of Wild Growht's ability. Blood Moon doesn't affect it.
4. Awaken the Ancient can be played on a non basic land if Blood Moon is in the battlefield. If Blood Moon leaves the battlefield, Awaken the Ancient will be put in the graveyard (unless the original land had the moutain subtype, like [Stomping Ground](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Stomping%20Ground)).
5. Yes, the lands still have the extra ability granted by Abundant Growth.

Comment: #4 Awaken the Ancients wouldn't pop off if the land is, for example, a [mtg:Stomping Ground]

Answer (score 2):

1. Yes. The lands are still not basic lands. They are non-basic lands that are mountains.
2. Urbog will have no effect, because as a mountain it will have lost its other abilities, including the swamp-making ability.

3,4,5, yes; the land will behave exactly like a regular mountain that has those enchantments on it.

Comment: @Pablo I see, oops